# "orion" is undefined when integrating orion editor in dojo

Tags: dojo, eclipse-orion

I am new to dojo and I am trying to integrate orion editor(build downloaded from http://download.eclipse.org/orion/) in dojo but I get the error "orion" is undefined.
The code looks like below:

1. HTML file for placing editor
   `<div data-dojo-attach-point="embeddedEditor"></div>`
2. A JS file

   ```
   require([
   "dojo/_base/declare", 
   "dijit/_WidgetBase",
   "editorBuild/code_edit/built-codeEdit-amd",
   "dijit/_TemplatedMixin",
   "dojo/text!orionEditor.html"
   ], function(declare,_WidgetBase,
   codeEditorAmd, _TemplatedMixin,template){
   declare("orionEditor", [_WidgetBase, 
   _TemplatedMixin], {

   templateString: template,

   postCreate: function(){
         var codeEdit = new orion.codeEdit();
           var contents = '';
               codeEdit.create({parent: this.embeddedEditor, contentType: "application/javascript", contents: contents}).
         then(function(editorViewer) {                         
           if (editorViewer.settings) {
                           editorViewer.settings.contentAssistAutoTrigger = true;
                           editorViewer.settings.showOccurrences = true;
                       }

                   });
        }
      });
     });
   ```
3. The orion editor build is placed in editorBuild folder.

Standalone orion works fine - http://libingw.github.io/OrionCodeEdit/
When integrating with dojo I am not sure why orion is undefined.
Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want using `orion` name in amd module then it has to be defined as parameter in function passed as require's callback.

Check [this guide](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Orion/How_Tos/Code_Edit#using_the_RequireJS_module_loader) - it has 2 solutions for using orion with amd modules.

Option 1 - define bundles once and use shorter name in all modules you need them:

```
require.config({
    bundles: {
        "editorBuild/code_edit/built-codeEdit-amd": ["orion/codeEdit", "orion/Deferred"]
    }       
});
require(
    ["orion/codeEdit", "orion/Deferred"], 
    function(mCodeEdit, Deferred) {
        var codeEdit = new mCodeEdit();
        var contents = 'var foo = "bar";'; 
        codeEdit.create({parent: "embeddedEditor"/*editor parent node id*/})
                .then(function(editorViewer) {
                    editorViewer.setContents(contents, "application/javascript");
                });
});
```

Option 2 - nested require:

```
require(["editorBuild/code_edit/built-codeEdit-amd"], function() {
    require(["orion/codeEdit", "orion/Deferred"], function(mCodeEdit, Deferred) {
    var codeEdit = new mCodeEdit();
    var contents = 'var foo = "bar";'; 
    codeEdit.create({parent: "embeddedEditor"/*editor parent node id*/})
            .then(function(editorViewer) {
                editorViewer.setContents(contents, "application/javascript");
            });
    });
});
```

Note: you can replace `mCodeEdit` with any unique name (That wouldn't shadow other objects/modules)

Comment: Thanks a lot. Worked well. :)